# select special form of a sentence in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am coding a chat bot using visual c#. I want to select some rows of my database that contains some sentences. I want to select the rows which their sentence is like an especial form. For example following code means:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE question= 'what % you % ing'
```

select the rows which column "question" begins with "what" ('%' means everything) and there is word 'you' in continue, and then 'ing' at the end.
for example: 'what are you doing' will be selected from this Table.
how can I code it? I have searched a lot, but I found nothing.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three issues with your sample code:

- The space before `ing`
- Case of the characters
- `=`

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE lower(question) like 'what % you %ing';
```

I suspect that you will find SQL rather limited for this application.  You will probably need to do a lot of work outside the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myTable
 WHERE question LIKE 'what % you %ing'
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f31d4/1)** demo